# x86_64 executable will not run when downloaded from remote server

Tags: linux, zip, executable

I made a x86_64 executable on my computer and it worked like a charm, so I put it in a .zip file and uploaded it to my web server. Then I redownloaded it onto my computer and now it won't run. When I double-click it, Linux says there are no programs associated with the file type. I am running Linux Mint Cinnamon 19.2.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else with this problem:
The executable needs to be marked as one in the properties menu. My bad, I'm an idiot.